# Rudin - Functional Analysis, exercise 1 - chapter 10,

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-algebras

> Use the identity $(xy)^n = x(yx)^{n-1}y$ to prove that $xy$ and $yx$ always have the same spectral radius. Both $x,y$ belongs to a Banach Algebra.

My attempt:

$(\lambda e - xy) = \sum_{j=0}^n (\lambda e)^j (xy)^{n-j}$ and then I tried to put $(xy)^{n-j} = x (yx)^{n-j-1} y$ and then try to spot something useful, but I'm not sure if it was the correct thing to do or not...

Comment: I forget, does Rudin cover the spectral radius formula in Chapter 10?

Comment: It defines both spectral radius and infers some properties about it with theorems etc...

Comment: Use the identity given to show that $r(xy)\leq r(yx)$ and $r(yx)\leq r(xy)$, equality follows. (Using the spectral radius formula, or similar.)

Comment: Does the definition suffices?

Comment: It may be possible, but I don't see how. The spectral radius formula is a much more natural thing to consider given the nature of the identity you are given.

Comment: Sorry i meant, with "spectral radius formula" do you mean the definition of spectral radius?

Comment: They probably mean theorem 10.13 which states $\rho(x)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\lVert x^n\rVert^{\frac{1}{n}}=\inf_{n\ge 1}\lVert x^n\rVert^{\frac{1}{n}}$.